# Send child of ArrayList to an Android Activity

Tags: android, inheritance, android-intent, android-activity, serializable

I want to send an object of a class - child of

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>
```

to an Android activity. This is my class:

```
package cz.honza.backpropagation.network.trainingset;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import cz.honza.backpropagation.network.parser.Csv;

public class TrainingLineBase extends ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> implements TrainingLine, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2777317734401540881L;

    @Override
    public String getEditorType() {
        return Csv.SIMPLE;
    }
}
```

It implements Serializable so I can simply use

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Serializable value)
```

method of Android Intent used to start that Activity. Then I try to read it back in the Activity's onCreate method

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_DATA);
```

Looks simple but it does not work. I do not get object of my TrainingLineBase class, I get

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>
```

which is its parent in the inheritance tree. It is holding the same data as the original TrainingLineBase. So it seems serialisation does not work well. The real data were transfered but the class type not.

Is it a bug in Android or am I doing anything incorrect?

Update: There is quite simple way to get a working solution. I can change inheritance to ownership. The neww class is serialized/deserialized well:

```
public class TrainingLineBase implements TrainingLine, Serializable {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> mData;
    // ....
```

Comment: have you tried casting it to TrainingLineBase, or checking the result of 
`getIntent().getSerializableExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_DATA) instanceof TrainingLineBase` ?

Comment: How are you putting the data?

Comment: Casting to TrainingLineBase causes ClassCastException because you cannot cast a parent to a child.

Comment: Putting data:

Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), TrainingLineBaseActivity.class);
i.putExtra(TrainingLineBaseActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_DATA,
  (Serializable)getItem(position)); // checked in debugger that it really is instance of TrainingLineBase
((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(i, position);

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I can suggest an alternative.

As is recommended at the bottom of the Android documentation of the Serializable interface at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html, encoding your class's state as JSON can be preferable to the stock Java serialization.

If you want to take this route, you can 'serialize' your object to a String using GSON or a similar JSON library, and put the result into a StringExtra on the Intent. Then, to deserialize, get the StringExtra from the Intent, a deserialize the JSON string using GSON. When using GSON, you specify the class of the object that you are attempting to deserialize.